# IIS Pool Recycling Configuration

Tags: iis

I have a asp.net website and i would host them with a IIS but

I'am noob with IIS configuration

so I have many Questions :

what is IIS Recycling ? and what is the Optimal parametres for IIS recycling for 6 ApplicationPool ?

Thank you

Comment: Recycling an app pool is just tearing down the process and spawning a new thread. Have you done ANY research of your own on IIS? If not, start here. https://www.iis.net/

Comment: Yes, but i can't understand what IIS Recycling and if he have any affect for the availabilty of application, and what is the optimal paramters for recycling 6 pool

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS manager and click on application pools. On the right side menu, you will find an option for setting application pool defaults. Clicking on that menu opens a dialogue box. Scroll down to the last and set the values as needed. Basically the time in minutes you wish your application pool to restart needs to be changed according to your site needs. This way you can set default rules for all sites in one IIS server.

If you want to change it for individual sites, right click on the particular application pool >> Recycling and set the values there.

You have options to restart IIS Application Pool based on minutes, memory, request and at regular time every day.

The values you set depends on the website or application you are serving.

The following link might give you a better insight.
[IIS Recycling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/)